# Avoid 'Enable/Disable Macros' MacOS prompt when programmatically opening a workbook

Tags: excel, vba, macos

[This topic has already been addressed in Stackoverflow but without providing a solution that works on a Mac]

I want to programmatically open a workbook that contains macros and wish to skip the 'Enable/Disable Macros' prompt that appears by default. I have tried a number of options but none seems to work. Would anyone know of a solution that works on the Mac ?

Excel 16.78.3 (oct 2023) / VBA 7.1 (2012 !) / macOS Sonoma 14.0 (latest) / MacBook Pro 13-inch M2

Note 1 :Is it possible that a solution does not exist due to the fact that msOffice's Trust Center is not available on the Mac ?

Note 2 : On the Mac it is possible to skip the 'Enable/Disable Macros' prompt by going to Microsoft Excel > Preferences > Security > 'Enable all macros'. This is a 'solution' that I obviously want to avoid as it would enable all macros on any workbook to run without my being warned -> extremely dangerous !

Many thanks in advance.

What I have written :

```
    Private Sub tst()
        
        'Save current values of relevant parameters
        
        secAutomation = Application.AutomationSecurity
        
        alertsDisplay = Application.DisplayAlerts
        
        eventsEnabled = Application.EnableEvents
        
        
        '======================
         
        'The following settings should avoid the display of the "enable/disable macros" dialog
    
        Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Described as having no effect on AutomationSecurity but just in case…
        
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'Again just in case…
        
        Workbooks.Open FileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/Book2.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=3
        
        'Problem : a prompt to enable/disable macros is still displayed
        
        '======================
        
        
        'Restore original settings
        
        Application.EnableEvents = eventsEnabled
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = alertsDisplay
        
        Application.AutomationSecurity = secAutomation
    
    End Sub 'tst
```

Comment: You can't get a macro to enable itself using VBA that would defeat the object of any form of security.